# Migration from play framework 2.0.8 to 2.1.0 Error unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, migration, playframework-2.1

I have migrated play framework from 2.0.8 to 2.1.0, everything was perfectly working before. Now i am getting following error:

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: hbllnd] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na]
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: hbllnd] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
>       at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: models.ProgramModule column: _ebean_intercept (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:681) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:703) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="hbllnd" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"  >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>hbllndDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>models.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my application.conf

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
 # If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the     same key!
application.secret="dAktNi/d>QGan4fFMnaecK;Bspp;DHQ/F5uU?    VM8<wUVpSJ0`;m]efM2E^^bsaFl"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# global=Global

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
#db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
#db.default.url="mysql://localhost:3306/test"
#db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#db.default.user=""
#db.default.password=""

## HBL L&D
db.hbllnd.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hbllnd"
db.hbllnd.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.hbllnd.user="root"
db.hbllnd.pass="root"
db.hbllnd.jndiName=hbllndDS

jpa.hbllnd=hbllnd

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a     logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

release.date=20141226
release.version="1.0.1"

# deployment version configuration
include "version.conf"

session.timeout=5
program.expire.days=30

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG

blog.testMode = true

# SMTP configuration
include "smtp.conf"

# play-easymail configuration
include "play-easymail.conf"
```

Can any one please let me know what's the issue??

EDIT: resolved it by disabling jBean.

Comment: `Repeated column in mapping for entity: models.ProgramModule column: _ebean_intercept (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`, have you disabled ebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved it by disabling jBean.